# How do you run a function after an element has been loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried to run the List_Sandbox functions after the each loop above has been ran and have to no avail figured it out. The each loop is selecting a group of checkboxes which then triggers a change event that renders other checkboxes that need to be selected. The List_Sandbox functions are doing the selection but the are running before my script can load the other new checkboxes. How can I see this through? I have tried, .load, .on, and livequery and neither is working. Please help...

```
$.each(zone_array, function(index, zone){
    $("ul.zones li input[id='"+zone+"']").attr("checked", "checked").trigger("change");
});
List_Sandbox.select_districts_versions(district_array);
List_Sandbox.select_stores_versions(store_array);


function data_for_districts(zoneid) {
            $.getJSON('/CampaignMgmt/GetDistrictsByZone', {'clientid': clientid, 'zone': zoneid }, function(data){
                $.each(data, function(index, value){
                    $("span.notice_district").remove();
                    var zone = value.toString().substring(0, 1);
                    var li_tag = '<li zone="'+zoneid+'" class="'+ value +'"style="display: list-item; "><label><input id="'+value+'" data-id="'+value+'" data-parent-id="'+zone+'" type="checkbox" name="zone_101" value="' + value + '"><span>'+ value +'</span></label></li>';
                    $("ul.districts").append(li_tag);
                    $('ul.districts li input[id="'+value+'"]').change(function(){
                        Districts.selection(value);
                        Districts.count_districts();
                    });
                });
            });
    }
```

Comment: What exactly does the change event do? It would be helpful if you included the code for that as well.

Comment: the change event registers a call for a checkbox list of districts which i wish to check after loading

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what your code that appends the checkboxes is doing but you could try the following:

```
var arr_length = zone_array.length;
$.each(zone_array, function(index, zone) {
    $("ul.zones li input[id='" + zone + "']").attr("checked", "checked").trigger("change");

    /* run the List_Sandbox functions after last item */
    if (index == arr_length - 1) {
        List_Sandbox.select_districts_versions(district_array);
        List_Sandbox.select_stores_versions(store_array);
    }
});
```

EDIT: SHould use `prop()` method instead of `attr()` if using jQuery >= 1.6

Comment: will prop() trigger a change event though? or do i need to do that on using .trigger() again?

Comment: no..use `trigger()` as you are doing  . Simply change attr() part to `.prop('checked',true)`

Comment: this will do what is already happening. the problem is the change event triggers some ajax, which, being async, is too late to the party.

Comment: if you are using ajax you need to show more code and explain what the `List` functions are doing

Comment: just posted the ajax that is called

Comment: try putting the each loop inside the $.getJSON, after the other `each` so that the array loop runs after the ajax is complete